# How to manage a large number of product variations?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am a developer and I am new to Prestashop world.

I am facing a problem to which I have not yet found the right way to respond to it with Prestashop.

I am building up a jewelry store which has a large product catalog (> 10k). The rings are available in materials (Gold for example) and in size (a 20en). The number of variations then increases very quickly. For 1000 products, 4 materials, 20 sizes, I already got 80k variations. And I am still far from the reality of the catalog.

I was able to test a similar catalog on a blank Prestashop, and it turns out that faceted search is greatly impacted by this volume, SQL queries easily take more than 10s, which is not viable.

The finger size is an information that is not "necessary" for the orders preparation, the same ring in different sizes has the same product code. Finger size could then be managed as a personalization option. On the other hand, a price delta can be applied to different sizes. And this delta varies depending on the material ... which does indeed look like a declination. The majority of rings, on the other hand, have NO price delta by size, this remains an exception.

I therefore ask for your help and continue my research in parallel.
Is there a way to optimize faceted search? (having analyzed the source code of the module, I would say no at first sight). Has anyone ever dealt with a very large product catalog?
If not, is there a module allowing to manage personalization options with a potential price by variation?
If no turnkey solution exists, what do you think is the best approach? (keep the declensions and solve the perf of the faceted search, thanks to Elasticsearch for example, or manage the sizes like a little advanced personalization?)

Thanks a lot for your help

Edit :

As asked, here is the slow SQL query, built by the natiuve facetedsearch module :

```sql
SELECT p.id_product,
       p.id_manufacturer,
       SUM(sa.quantity) as quantity,
       p.condition,
       p.weight,
       p.price,
       cp.position
FROM ps_product p
         LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute pa ON (p.id_product = pa.id_product)
         LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute_combination pac ON (pa.id_product_attribute = pac.id_product_attribute)
         LEFT JOIN ps_stock_available sa ON (p.id_product = sa.id_product AND
                                             IFNULL(pac.id_product_attribute, 0) = sa.id_product_attribute AND
                                             sa.id_shop = 1 AND sa.id_shop_group = 0)
         INNER JOIN ps_category_product cp ON (p.id_product = cp.id_product)
         INNER JOIN ps_category c ON (cp.id_category = c.id_category AND c.active = 1)
         INNER JOIN ps_product_shop ps ON (p.id_product = ps.id_product AND ps.id_shop = 1 AND ps.active = TRUE)
WHERE ((pac.id_attribute = 1))
  AND p.visibility IN ('both', 'catalog')
  AND c.nleft >= 3
  AND c.nright <= 4
  AND ps.id_shop = '1'
GROUP BY p.id_product
```

The table `ps_product_attribute` contains 600k rows, and `ps_product_attribute_combination` 1.2M rows.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mind sharing which SQL query is taking that much time ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for yout reply. I added the sql query.

Comment: This is weird to perform a query on the whole database since it will most likely never be desplayed at once. I think this module was not designed to act on big DB and might rely a little bit too much on cache.

Comment: Hi @EmmanuelDaFonseca, under mysql it looks like what's slow is 'Copying To Tmp Table' step (almost 99.9% of time spent to process this query). As you have probably no control over this query you might have a glance at server config to improve performance (system variables, mounting ramdisk for tmpdir...).

Comment: This is insane to performe such query on such a big set. This module is clearly not made for big database. You can use the "explain" statement to see where the problem is, but to me the biggest problem is that the request actually fetch the whole database even if only a very small part of it will be used. You need to fix the module for the query to use pagination (https://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/26/faster-sql-paging-with-jooq-using-the-seek-method/).

Comment: This is weird since facetedsearch has some LIMIT clause on its "search result" mechanism. However I couldnt check all the code paths for the filters (dynamic query building makes it hard to follow).

Comment: In fact this is weird, i will double check that, maybe I debugged the queyr too early in code ! Anyway, my datanase tool makes limits in background, and thé query stay  slow.

Comment: I tried the query with a LIMIT of 10 and the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should stay with your variations (I think prestashop calls them combinations), creating a custom pricing mechanism would be a pain since you would have to implement it on different locations and some modules might even directly check for prices in DB. Also most of prestashop queries are simple and properly use ids, therefore they are fast enough to deal with large DB.

ps_facetedsearch is a module that uses some index tables. Maybe this index is slow or maybe it takes some time to build. If the index building is slow you can trigger it from time to time (after a catalog import or product modification). If it is slow by nature your best bet is to make your own facetedsearch module, with a more efficient index.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Maybe I don't understand how really work the native facetedsearch module, but It seems that the index is not used to perform the search Query (see edit in my post). Otherwise, I agree, combinations seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Since I might face the same problem as you I'm going to dive deeper in the code and see if there's a quick fix